# Which new features and changes are planned for Unity in 11.10?

Tags: unity, development, 11.10

Reading the planet and several blogs regularly, and also testing 11.10, it still is not clear to me what is planned for Unity in 11.10. When going to [[image: go to launchpad] launchpad](https://launchpad.net/unity), no blueprints are available and the open bugs are mostly just fixes or backlog from 11.04.

That makes me wonder what is planned for unity in 11.10 at all? Is there any public documentation available about this topic? Or could some developers make a statement here?
It would undoubtedly be very interesting for many to get some information on this!

Comment: This question never got a satisfying answer as things like the new dash design were never announced to the public before they ultimately landed in Oneiric. Adding an answer a posteriori does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

They'll be distributing it with both Gnome 3 and a slightly-closer-to-ready version of Unity,

So, Unity will be able to display progress bars, notifications and little circles with numbers on the fly, like you might see in a Chromium-style plugin. I know, sounds small, but it's something. Third parties will also be able to write their own "lenses", which will let you search, for example, Youtube from your desktop -- IE, the search that happens when you hit the super button -- and browse interesting content from there.

They're going to integrate the Software Center with Unity a little more, not that I have any idea what that means.

I found those new features in these article: http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/05/6-important-changes-in-next-ubuntu-1110.html, http://www.junauza.com/2011/05/ubuntu-1110-oneiric-ocelot-features.html. But I'm sure there are a couple more features (mainly focusing on integration) in the works, as well as a nice pile of bug fixes. You'll also get Unity 2D, but I doubt you particularly care, unless you run a 5-year old 11 inch laptop.

Comment: You forgot to mention point 5 in the second link about lenses and quick lists. Also, the amount of old or weaker hardware should not be underestimated.

Comment: Yeah. Added a brief bit on lenses. And I know that old hardware matters, but if this guy is already itching for the next version, I think it's probably because he wants something newer and upgraded, not the hot new fallback option.